# Bazel Android c++_shared/c++_static issues

Tags: android, c++, bazel

We have a project that uses a library that is built on top of Google's [Mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe), which is built using the `Bazel` build system.

The project itself is an Android Native Library, built using Gradle with CMake

```
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++17 -fopenmp -static-openmp -fexceptions -frtti -Wl,-s -Wno-unused-command-line-argument"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared", "-DOpenCV_DIR=${opencvDir}", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
            }
        }
```

So we end up with 2 (or more later, also dependent on OpenCV for example) shared object libraries - the actual `SDK` & the `Mediapipe` project.

We're seeing issues that are similar to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29377), which lead me to look into the runtime part of our project.

```
E/libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_cast: std::bad_cast
```

I saw [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29377#issuecomment-855347478) comment on that issue thread, and adding

```
System.loadLibrary("c++_shared");
```

Solved the crash.

However, this is not a practical solution as the project we're building would provide a native SDK in the form of multiple `.so` files and I wouldn't want to force our clients to have to explicitly load the shared runtime library before using our library.

The gradle library has `"-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared"` flag, so this is using the shared one, but I couldn't find any way to compile Mediapipe (with Bazel) using `c++_shared`. I couldn't find any reference to using shared runtime when compiling Bazel projects (except for [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7475), which isn't exactly relevant and the solution didn't help me)

We might be able to work around this by setting `-DANDROID_STL=c++_static`, but this has other issues, mainly, it violates [Android's guidelines](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#shared_runtimes) for using multiple shared libraries, though it might be possible for for [middleware vendors](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/middleware-vendors#using_the_stl)

So the question is,

- Is it possible to build Mediapipe (or any other Bazel based) using `c++_shared` Android STL
- If not, are there any other options to solve the runtime conflicts
- Is it even a runtime conflict or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working as suggested by using `c++_static` on all of our shared objects (SDK, Mediapipe, OpenCV and others)