# SIGABRT when exception is thrown from .so in Android when 3rd party lib is used statically

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have a native Android, SDK style library which depends on OpenCV.

In order to avoid conflict when a user uses the library and their own usage with OpenCV, I want to compile OpenCV statically into my library and hide its symbols.

I compiled OpenCV (3.4.13 `world` module) statically and used it, along with its 3rd party libraries in my library.

When I try and use my library, and it throws an exception, even if the exception is caught by the user, a `SIGABRT` is causing the app to terminate.

This is the stack trace from the logcat

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 24115 (.test), pid 24115 (.test)
...
A/DEBUG: backtrace:
A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 0000000000051948  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168) (BuildId: 931371c1098ffd5adc489b9ff4da8e82)
A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 00000000000b2ba0  /data/app/~~gc4ZOfzcr7C0hRfmsieCtQ==/com.example.test-sx2ESCfGCsi3lXPZWnk9nA==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (BuildId: ece72a2ebc3774a1be9fd21271258acd3bcdfaa7)
A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 00000000000aec8c  /data/app/~~gc4ZOfzcr7C0hRfmsieCtQ==/com.example.test-sx2ESCfGCsi3lXPZWnk9nA==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (__gxx_personality_v0+348) (BuildId: ece72a2ebc3774a1be9fd21271258acd3bcdfaa7)
A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 00000000004dd2dc  /data/app/~~gc4ZOfzcr7C0hRfmsieCtQ==/com.example.test-sx2ESCfGCsi3lXPZWnk9nA==/base.apk!libmylib.so (BuildId: 790f2880373cb985055ab9b7b2efc48b1afb82fd)
A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 00000000004dd7e4  /data/app/~~gc4ZOfzcr7C0hRfmsieCtQ==/com.example.test-sx2ESCfGCsi3lXPZWnk9nA==/base.apk!libmylib.so (BuildId: 790f2880373cb985055ab9b7b2efc48b1afb82fd)
A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0000000000170600  /data/app/~~gc4ZOfzcr7C0hRfmsieCtQ==/com.example.test-sx2ESCfGCsi3lXPZWnk9nA==/base.apk!libmylib.so (mylib::TestClass::TestClass(char const*, char const*)+908) (BuildId: 790f2880373cb985055ab9b7b2efc48b1afb82fd)
A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 000000000000c5d0  /data/app/~~gc4ZOfzcr7C0hRfmsieCtQ==/com.example.test-sx2ESCfGCsi3lXPZWnk9nA==/base.apk!libJnilibrary.so (BuildId: 7f3605ea8cb95dc87864e3df22f6b77b46c2e592)
A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000000000000c3b8  /data/app/~~gc4ZOfzcr7C0hRfmsieCtQ==/com.example.test-sx2ESCfGCsi3lXPZWnk9nA==/base.apk!libJnilibrary.so (BuildId: 7f3605ea8cb95dc87864e3df22f6b77b46c2e592)
A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 000000000000c308  /data/app/~~gc4ZOfzcr7C0hRfmsieCtQ==/com.example.test-sx2ESCfGCsi3lXPZWnk9nA==/base.apk!libJnilibrary.so (Java_com_example_lib_Engine_cxxInit+56) (BuildId: 7f3605ea8cb95dc87864e3df22f6b77b46c2e592)
A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 00000000002d7644  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148) (BuildId: 2b417e2566f5eb686666666b6ee952ea)
```

(It also happens if the JNI library uses `c++_static`, but in that case the `__gxx_personality_v0` and 1 above it come from the `libJnilibrary.so`)

If I compile OpenCV as a shared library and link my library against it, then everything works fine.

I've had issues with exceptions in my library before, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72528728/975959) question I asked. I solved it by compiling everything using `c++_static` STL. The problem looks similar to [this](https://github.com/android/ndk/issues/1434), and indeed I was missing the `key function`, but even after adding it, the problem keeps happening.

I looked at the symbols using `llvm-readelf -CWs` and noticed that when OpenCV is linked dynamically, in addition to OpenCV symbols, the output contains some ndk and cxxabi symbols which doesn't exist when OpenCV is used statically. I don't know if it's related at all but for example

```
110: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND std::uncaught_exception()
...
201: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info
...
231: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND std::__ndk1::to_string(unsigned int)
```

(All of these are missing when using statically built OpenCV)

I'm using ndk version `21e` (I can't use higher version at the moment because another library uses `Bazel` and it only supports up to 21 at the moment)

OpenCV is built with the following flags

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DINSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DANDROID_EXAMPLES_WITH_LIBS=OFF -DANDROID_ABI="arm64-v8a" 
-DBUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_DOCS=OFF -DWITH_OPENCL=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=1 
-DANDROID_STL=c++_static -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake" 
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_FAT_JAVA_LIB=OFF -DBUILD_JAVA=OFF -DINSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB=ON -DINSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF
-DBUILD_opencv_video=ON -DBUILD_opencv_videoio=ON -DBUILD_opencv_features2d=ON -DBUILD_opencv_flann=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_highgui=ON -DBUILD_opencv_ml=OFF 
-DBUILD_opencv_photo=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_python=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_shape=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_superres=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_ts=OFF 
-DBUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF -DBUILD_ANDROID_PROJECTS=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_world=ON -DBUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_core=ON -DBUILD_opencv_imgcodecs=ON 
-DBUILD_opencv_imgproc=ON -DBUILD_opencv_calib3d=ON -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install -DBUILD_ZLIB=1 -DWITH_PROTOBUF=OFF -DWITH_QUIRC=OFF ..
```

My libray is compiled using Gradle and Android Studio with these CMake flags

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-std=c++17 -static-openmp -fopenmp -fexceptions -frtti -Wno-unused-command-line-argument -Wl,-s"
        cppFlags "-Wl,--exclude-libs,libc++_static.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libc++abi.a"
        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static", "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't related to the 3rd party or anything like this at all eventually.

I was using NDK version `r21e`. Upgrading the NDK to `r24` fixed the issue.

It seems that when linking `OpenCV` as a shared object, it masked the actual NDK bug by importing or including some of the missing/problematic symbols and when we stopped using it, the error appeared.